# How Do You Iterate Through An JObject If You Are Deleting Certain Elements?

Tags: c#, json, collections, json.net

Summary:

With the US Department of Education API, I plan on creating a list of colleges and the median salary for their computer science graduates. However, many schools have null values and attempting to remove the null values breaks the code as you cannot modify a collection while enumerating through it.

My denullifier code:

```cs
static JObject DeNullifier(JObject inputJson)
{
    //Each school in the results[] section
    foreach(var school in inputJson["results"])
    {
        //Each degree in the cip_4_digit section
        foreach(var degree in school["latest.programs.cip_4_digit"])
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(degree["earnings.median_earnings"].Value<string>()))
            {
                degree.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return inputJson;
}
```

JSON Shortened Version:

```
{
    "metadata": 
    {
        "total": 1444,
        "page": 14,
        "per_page": 100
    },

    "results": 
    [
        {
            "school.name": "Georgia College & State University",
            "latest.programs.cip_4_digit": 
            [
                {
                  "earnings.median_earnings": 53200,
                  "title": "Computer Science.",
                  "code": "1107"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "school.name": "Georgia Southern University",
            "latest.programs.cip_4_digit": 
            [
                {
                  "earnings.median_earnings": null,
                  "title": "Computer Science.",
                  "code": "1107"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Newtonsoft JSON.NET Class References:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm

Comment: Have you tried to use a copy of that object

Comment: I can create a copy of the object, but then removing the copy wouldn't do anything to the original.

Comment: Actually, you just gave me an idea. Create a new JObject then add the valid elements to it. The only downside is the inefficiency but I'll attempt to try this method.

Comment: You are iterating through the entire json anyway, and cant delete from the jobject you are iterating. You can use this item as a skeleton and delete from copy item

Comment: Creating g a copy would work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the nodes to remove to a different collection and then remove them. For example,

```
static JObject DeNullifier(JObject inputJson)
{
    var nodesToRemove = new List<JToken>();
    //Each school in the results[] section
    foreach(var school in inputJson["results"])
    {
        //Each degree in the cip_4_digit section
        foreach(var degree in school["latest.programs.cip_4_digit"])
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(degree["earnings.median_earnings"].Value<string>()))
            {
                nodesToRemove.Add(degree);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach(var node in nodesToRemove)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
    return inputJson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by combining your code with `Where` method from standard `Linq` (without making a copy of source collection)

```cs
static JObject DeNullifier(JObject inputJson)
{
    foreach (var school in inputJson["results"])
    {
        var degrees = (JArray)school["latest.programs.cip_4_digit"];
        var nullDegrees = degrees.Where(t => t["earnings.median_earnings"].Type == JTokenType.Null).ToList();

        foreach (var nullDegree in nullDegrees)
            degrees.Remove(nullDegree);
    }

    return inputJson;
}
```

You just select all `latest.programs.cip_4_digit` nodes, where `earnings.median_earnings` value is null, and than remove these items from array.

`ToList()` will elevate the tokens with null values into new collection and help to avoid `InvalidOperationException` during removal